# Model History Revert button remove in Django Admin

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-admin, django-simple-history

[Revert button hide or remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4Yqa.png)

How to hide this revert button or remove their functionally in model history in Django admin side

But I do not change HTML template.
only override the revert fun calling (_save fun call )

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished natively by adding `SIMPLE_HISTORY_REVERT_DISABLED=True` to the bottom of your `settings.py` file

For further documentation please check this section in the [manual](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin.html#disabling-the-option-to-revert-an-object)